# Passing a function to Promise.then results in a different behaviour than passing a nested function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

The following code

```
function doSomething(msg){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          console.log(msg);
          resolve();
        }, 
        2000);
    }) 
}

let start = Date.now();  
let end;  
doSomething("1st Call")
  .then(()=>doSomething("2nd Call"))
  .then(()=>doSomething("3rd Call"))
  .then(()=>{
    end = Date.now();
    console.log('start',start);
    console.log('end',end);
    console.log('elapsed time',end-start);
  })
```

prints 1st Call, 2nd and 3rd, with 2 seconds between each console.log statement, as expected

[image]

However, if I remove the arrow functions from the then blocks, the behaviour is totally different, i.e

```
doSomething("1st Call")
  .then(doSomething("2nd Call"))
  .then(doSomething("3rd Call"))
  .then(()=>{
    end = Date.now();
    console.log('start',start);
    console.log('end',end);
    console.log('elapsed time',end-start);
  })
```

With this code, all the console.log statements get printed at the same time, and the elapsed time is just 2 seconds, as opposed to 2 seconds per function (6 seconds total as in the first example)

[image]

In other words, for the code to work correctly, the then function needs to take a function (the arrow one in this case), and from inside that function, then I can do further function calls.

Why can't I just pass the function directly, why does it need to be nested in another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.then()` expects a callback function which will be called when the `Promise` on which `.then()` method is called - fulfills.

When you do this

```
.then(doSomething("2nd Call"))
```

instead of registering a callback function which will be invoked at some later time, `doSomething()` is called *immediately*.

You could pass a reference to a function to the `.then()` method and `.then()` will call that function when `Promise` fulfills.

```
.then(doSomething)
```

but you won't be able to pass any argument to `doSomething` function.

`.then(doSomething("2nd Call"))` will only work if `doSomething` returns a function. In that case, returned function will be registered as a callback and will be called when `Promise` fulfills.

You could use `.bind()` to get a function which will be used as a callback to `.then()` method

```js
function doSomething(msg){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(msg);
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
    }); 
}

let start = Date.now();  
let end;  

doSomething("1st Call")
  .then(doSomething.bind(null, '2nd Call'))
  .then(doSomething.bind(null, '3rd Call'))
  .then(()=>{
    end = Date.now();
    console.log('start',start);
    console.log('end',end);
    console.log('elapsed time',end-start);
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `then(fn())`, it will not return a value for the next `.then(...)` to use, so it can continue immediately.

When you use `.then(variable => fn())`, the next `.then(...)` will wait for the first to resolve or reject.

It's similar to the difference between the functions

```
function a () {
   stuff
}

function b (){
  return stuff
}
```